# How to generate a vector of repeating elements for a given length

Tags: matlab

For a given length, `T`, I would like to have an ordered sequence repeated until it reaches `T`. The ordered sequence is `v = (1:12)'`.

```
If T = 12, the output vector should be v

If T = 13, the output vector should be v and in addition the first element of v, thus [v; v(1)]

If T = 15, the output vector should be [v; v(1); v(2); v(3)]

If T = 24, the output vector should be [v; v]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved it using modulo:

```
T = 800

v             = (1:12)';
nbRest        = mod(T,length(v));
nbFit         = floor(T/length(v));
currentMonths = [repmat(v, nbFit,1); v(1:nbRest)];
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use indexing together with the modulo operator to solve this. The only complication is MATLAB's 1-based indexing. We generate indices `1:T`, then use `mod` to wrap those around. Because of 1-based indexing, we need to subtract 1 from the indices before applying `mod`, then add 1 again:

```
v = 1:12;
T = 15;
output = v(mod(0:T-1,numel(v))+1)
```

Comment: Ah beated me to it !